# Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation

Tags: .net, serialization, soap, axis

I ran into a problem when communicating with SOAP Axis web service using Service Reference method with dotNet.

It seems when dotNet client deserializing the incoming xml steam, it expects an array, but it actually gets a single object. I thought that there might be an issue with the xml message sent from the web service, but it looks normal.

Error message:

```
Cannot assign object of type WebService.MessagingServices_SendMultiSMS_SendSuccess to an object of type WebService.MessagingServices_SendMultiSMS_SendSuccess[]. The error occurred while reading node with id='id1'.
```

SOAP XML message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><ns1:sendMultiSMSResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://DefaultNamespace"><sendMultiSMSReturn href="#id0"/></ns1:sendMultiSMSResponse><multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:MessagingServices_SendMultiSMSResult" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="urn"><CallSuccess xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</CallSuccess><CallErrorMessage xsi:type="xsd:string">Success</CallErrorMessage><SMSCount xsi:type="xsd:int">2</SMSCount><MultiSMSPostedList href="#id1"/><MultiSMSPostedList href="#id2"/></multiRef><multiRef id="id2" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns3:MessagingServices_SendMultiSMS_SendSuccess" xmlns:ns3="urn" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><gRecipientName xsi:type="xsd:string">Me</gRecipientName><gRecipientMSISDNwithCC xsi:type="xsd:string">xxxxxx1</gRecipientMSISDNwithCC><gOutMsgID xsi:type="xsd:int">314437688</gOutMsgID></multiRef><multiRef id="id1" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns4:MessagingServices_SendMultiSMS_SendSuccess" xmlns:ns4="urn" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><gRecipientName xsi:type="xsd:string">Me</gRecipientName><gRecipientMSISDNwithCC xsi:type="xsd:string">xxxxxx2</gRecipientMSISDNwithCC><gOutMsgID xsi:type="xsd:int">314437687</gOutMsgID></multiRef></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```